# How do I get a clipping mask to actually cut strokes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

I have some map data that I've pulled together from openstreetmap, which has streets marked up as paths.  Now, I need to clip the paths with a clipping mask.

[image]

Clips to

[image]

As noted above, the streets are vectors, and if you select them you can see the objects off the side of the clipping path.  How can one clip the paths with the clipping mask and flatten the clip afterwards?

The 'crop' tool in the path finder flatly refuses to do this.

Comment: Have you tried `Object > Flatten Transparency`?

Comment: Sorta kinda works but it generates outlines around the strokes and turns them into filled objects.   I need to preserve and edit the paths after tidying up the crud outside the clipping mask.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like "split everything under the selected  path" Unfortunately Adobe doesn't want it, but you have some workarounds. One of them is the shape builder.

[image]

My original map is in the left. I selected all and Alt+Clicked with the shape builder every tail outside the red path. Everything clicked vanished and nothing was combined inside the red path.

Dragging over holding the Alt key works, too.